# Jumping to a specific byte (white space included)

Tags: point

How can I move the point to a specific byte (not a char), as I understand `goto-char` doesn't consider space characters. But in a large file I need to find to a specific byte, taking into account also all white space characters e.g. new line, space, tabs etc.

Comment: Why do you think that `goto-char` ignores white-space?  It doesn't.

Comment: What would your requirement mean if the byte in question was not a whole char?  Do you want a buffer with no character encoding, perhaps?

Comment: The question isn't too clear. When you say move "to a specific byte" do you mean (1) move to byte number *N* in the buffer or (2) then next byte in the buffer whose *value* is some number *N*? Is this about the byte's *position* (you gave the question tag `point`) in the buffer or its *value* (you speak of SPC chars)?